# What brand is this handlebar stem?

Tags: handlebars, stem

I just purchased a used bike recently and I am curious to the make of my handlebar stem.
Would anyone be able to identify the brand logo?
[image]

Comment: @dotjoe glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe that's the logo for Dyno which was acquired by GT in the '80s.

[image]

Comment: This image seems to confirm that it's Dyno: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc6/188078_122928847746880_78100500_n.jpg

Comment: Awesome. I hunted around a bit for an image to confirm that but I guess their logo evolved a bit over time because I couldn't find anything that quite matched.

Comment: +1, not for knowing it was Dyno (who sponsored the nicest person/rider you could ever met, Dave Volker) but that they were taken over by GT too!!

Answer (score 3):

It's either Dyno, or Diamond Back.

Comment: Yes, confirming Dyno - definitely not Diamond Back which is always shortened to DB not a single D